# How to add dependency for xcframeworks in SPM Package

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, dependency-management, swift-package-manager

I have created xcframework for.eg. MobileCoreFramework and distributed it through MobileCoreSPM,
here is MobilecoreSPM package,

```
    name: "MobileCoreSPM",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MobileCoreSPM",
            targets: ["MobileCoreSPM","MobileCoreFramework"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [

    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MobileCoreSPM",
            dependencies: ["MobileCoreFramework"]),
        .binaryTarget(name: "MobileCoreFramework", path: "Artifacts/MobileCoreFramework.xcframework"),
    ]
)
```

then created another XCframework i.e. BillpayFramework which depends on MobileCoreFramework, here when creating BillpayFramework, I used MobileCoreSPM as dependent package and used MobilecoreMethods inside Billpay class, which was working fine.

but when tried to distribute BillpayFramework through BillpaySPM, error is displayed like it x-product 'MobileCoreFramework' required by package 'billpaylib' target 'BillpaySPM' not found.

```
let package = Package(
    name: "BillpaySPM",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "BillpaySPM",
            targets: ["BillpaySPM"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(path: "/Users/com/Documents/POC/Try2/MobileCoreLib"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "BillpaySPM",
            dependencies: ["BillpayFramework","MobileCoreFramework",
                          ]),
        .binaryTarget(name: "BillpayFramework", path: "Artifacts/BillpayFramework.xcframework"),
    ]
)
```

And I am trying all this in my machine locally, didnt host it in github yet, hence linked everything through localpath.

Error:

product 'MobileCoreFramework' required by package 'billpaylib' target 'BillpaySPM' not found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwhaE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify the name of the dependent library if it's not identical with package name:

```swift
targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
   .target(
       name: "BillpaySPM",
       dependencies: [
          "BillpayFramework",
          .product(name: "MobileCoreFramework", package: "MobileCoreLib"),
        ]),
...
```

Comment: Still I am getting error like this -  product 'MobileCoreFramework' required by package 'billpaylib' target 'BillpaySPM' not found in package 'MobileCoreLib'. Is there any problem in a way MobileCoreFramework is exposed?

Comment: where's 'billpaylib'? I can't see it in package manifest

Comment: BillpayLib is the packageName when I created, I mean it is like in xcode I could see this package file resides inside BillpayLib folder

Comment: try `.package(name: "MobileCoreLib", path: "../<relative path to  library>/MobileCoreLib"),` the path is relative to where this `Package.swift` is located.

Comment: Now with this I could see the package MobileCoreLib getting added as dependent package in BillpayLib Package, but still it says it couldnt find the product MobileCoreFramework Inside MobileCoreLib package, Is there any issues in the way I created MobileCoreLib package?

Comment: based on your first post you need to add dependency like this: `          .product(name: "MobileCoreSPM", package: "MobileCoreSPM"),
`